# CodeIgniter: Global Vars via Controller and Indirect modification of overloaded property

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, oop

A problem haunting me since early days of CodeIgniter and now, with the new CI 3 i want to see if there is a more elegant way to solve it.

```
// file: application/core/MY_Controller.php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

   public $GLO;

   function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->GLO['foo'] = 'bar';
      $this->GLO['arr'] = array();
   }
}
```

then, later in the code, I need to get and set the values of the $GLO variable dynamically. So for instance:

```
// file: application/controllers/dispatcher.php
class Dispatcher extends MY_Controller {

   function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('public/langs');
     print_r($this->GLO);
   }
}
```

will print `array('foo'=>'bar, 'arr'=>Array())` which is correct. Also in my models I can get the values of the $GLO array in the same manner. However, as soon as I need to set any values in the $GLO array, I get the `Indirect modification of overloaded property notice` and so I am stuck. In my model (after executing a DB query):

```
// file: application/models/public/langs.php
class Langs extends CI_Model {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();  
}

function set_global_languages(){
  print_r($this->GLO); // <<< prints the same values as in the controller above
  $temp = array();
  // [stripped db code]
  $temp['label'] = $row->label;
  $temp['id'] = $row->id;      
  $this->GLO['arr'][] = $temp; // <<< this is where the notice happens
}
```

Any clues of how I can use `$this->GLO['foo'] = 'baz';` for setting properties of this global array in my models?

Cheers.

Comment: What is the relation of MY_Controller GLO and CI_Model GLO? I didn't get it.

Comment: The idea is to declare a global variable in the controller and use it within other controllers and models of the application. $this->GLO should refer to the same public $GLO throughout the app.

Comment: But you are defining it to My_Controller class scope. Looks like that is why you can't reach it from model scope. See more about class, $this variable. $this is not a global var.

Comment: It seems like I can read the var, but I can't set the var - although it is in a different scope? Hmm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sintakonte**, thanks a lot for the tip. Last night I had to rewrite a lot of code to see if and how it works. The Registry class works as expected! The only issue with this set/get method is the handling of deep arrays, especially those created dynamically and having their data pushed dynamically too. So today morning I did something very bad :) and just created this class:

```
class Globals {
  public $data = array();
}
```

So now I am going from `$this->GLO['foo']` to `$this->globals->data['foo']` and get to keep existing syntax intact! It also enables me to reuse the class in different controllers *and* models under different names, once initializing it as "globals" and the other time as "admin". Seems to work alright, too!

Comment: hehe, its not thaaat dirty if its embedded as library ;)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this problem a ton of times. Since you are asking for an elegant solution - i try to give you some idea.

There is a library called Registry, which is written totally fine and can be extended any time. You can find the library [here](https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-registry/blob/master/Registry.php).

Put it in your libraries folder.
This library should get autoloaded so it is always available.
Add it to your config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(...,"Registry");
```

After that you should have a really easy way of storing things globally within CI - in your code for example it would look like

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $arrSomething = [
            'foo' => "bar",
            "arr" => array()
        ];
        $this->registry->set("arrSomething",$arrSomething);
    }
}

class Dispatcher extends MY_Controller 
{

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('public/langs');
    }
}

class Langs extends CI_Model 
{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    function set_global_languages()
    {
        $arrSomething = $this->registry->get("arrSomething");
        $temp = array();
        // [stripped db code]
        $temp['label'] = $row->label;
        $temp['id'] = $row->id;      
        $arrSomething['arr'][] = $temp;

        //in case of an array i guess you've to reset it because there is no reference or try to call it by reference with "&"
        $this->registry->set("arrSomething");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I did something dirty :) after trying this class. See my answer.