# set global variable for HMVC codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter.
I want to set a global variable for my helpers, models, and controllers.
the variable is getting from database..

Here is the example:

**don't know where to put the variable**

```
 $this->load->model('test');
 $data = $this->test->get_code();
 $this->code = $data["code"]; //main global variable
```

**my helper**

```
function test() {
    if($this->code=="test") {

    }
}
```

**my controller**

```
function index() {
    echo $this->code;
}
```

**my model**

```
function get_data() {
     $query = $this->db->get_where('my_table', array('code' => $this->code));
     return $query->row_array();
}
```

As you can see my scripts above, `$this->code` is almost used for `my helper`, `my controller`, and `my model`.
Where should i put the variable so that i can access the variable by using `$this->code` only to all?

Comment: Try using code in a separate library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505673/codeigniter-global-vars-via-controller-and-indirect-modification-of-overloaded/40527230#40527230

Comment: @Hekmat how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can crate MY_Controller in extends MX_Controller in application/core folder and extends MY_Controller in Application/module create you own controller.EX see below

```
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {
    public $code = "";  // Global variable 

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('test');
       $data = $this->test->get_code();
       $this->code = $data["code"]; //main global variable
    }

}

class Admin extends MY_Controller {
   function index() {
    echo $this->code;
   }
}
```

Comment: that's for controller only? so how about helpers and models?

Comment: helper not required you can set method in MY_controller and model use same as all load model in autoload.php and use anywhere.

Comment: but i need `function test()` helper for controllers and models. autoload? i have so many models that must be used in global variables. is it the right way if i loaded all the models to autoload?

Comment: you can't use controller global variable in helper so you create test() method in my_conteroller and use for all controller if you have extends

Answer (score 1):

Try put data to session:

```
$this->load->model('test');
$data = $this->test->get_code();

$this->load->library('session');    
$this->session->set_userdata('name' => $data );
```

and

```
function test() {
  $this->load->library('session');
  $data = $this->session->userdata('name');
    if($data=="test") {

    }
}

function index() {
    $this->load->library('session');
    $data = $this->session->userdata('name');
}
```

You may use session without load in every function, 
add in config/autoload.php

```
    $autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```